# Identifying object overlaps in a 3D space

Tags: data-structures, 3d, iteration

I have a set of 3D objects (points, triangles, lines). I would like to split these objects where they overlap. In order to do this, I want to compare each pair of objects which overlaps in 3D space.

I only need to do the operation once, though the new split objects need to be added to the list of 3D objects to check for further overlaps.

Is there an efficient data structure to put the objects into to do this kind of iteration? Would the cost of builidng such a structure be greater than sorting the objects along one axis and iterating a front and back axis coordinate to keep track of overlapping objects.

Comment: In the end I decided to avoid this approach and used a Binary Space Partition (BSP) tree instead. It would still be interesting if there's a good answer for this question as building a BSP is slow.